# Bluetooth doesn't see Logitech k375s in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, 21.04

I am new to ubuntu and I have installed ubuntu 21.04 a couple of hours ago and I have serious problem with bluetooth. So my keyboard Logitech k375s is not even visible to bluetooth and my mouse is visible but not pairing.

Can you please help me diagnose the problem?

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you've done and/or what you're seeing on the screen?